# Deleting Files in a Directory that contain a single quote (') character

Tags: grep, rm

I Have files as such:
"contrail's",
hello
, "larch's"...etc

How could I delete files that contain a single  quote (') character(ex: "kibosh's" ).

I was thinking in using  grep to find the files with single  quote (') characters and using rm to delete the files.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grep searches file contents, not the files' names.

The shell is typically what you use to select the set of files to work on.
To name all the files in the current directory with a single quote, you'd use the pattern `*\'*`. (A backslash is used to escape characters that otherwise would have meaning to the shell.)

To list them:

```
ls *\'*
```

To delete them:

```
rm *\'*
```